# Delete raster values lower than 0

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I work with raster layers (tif). I have to seperate buildings and vegetation (trees) from a DSM.

DSM - DTM with the rastercalculater gives me the buildings and the trees. (DSM and DOM combined)

But then I get where no trees or buildings are numbers like -0.00332... how can I "delete" those values from my new raster that all values under 2 are = 0?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @thenewgisguy! Could you please clarify: do you want to remove all values less than 2 or all values less than 0 or change all values under 2 to 0 (or nodata)?

Comment: You could arrange your new table on these Z-values and simply delete all these features below 2 or use the field calculator to change every value under 2 to NULL or 0.

Answer (score 9):

Use raster calculator to set all values under 2 to 0:

```
("DEM@1">=2)*"DEM@1"
```

[image]

`"DEM@1"` represents the name of your layer (difference layer).

The output of `"DEM@1">=2` will be a layer with 0 and 1 values. 1 if condition is TRUE and 0 for false. `1 * "DEM@1"` will maintain original values (TRUE condition) and the other ones will be 0's.